# Retrieve Data From NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I have an Editable NSTextView,In which user will write using different font style, on certain action i need to prepare the HTML Formate of it, 
Can anyone suggest me, how i can retrieve the data from NSTextView, 
I am able to use

```
[[pInputText textStorage] words];
```

but it returns NSArray, from which i am not able to get NSMutableString,

Can anyone suggest me the best possible way to retrieve the String/data what user typed and in which format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below solutions works for me,

```
- (NSString *)convertUnderlineTextToHTML:(NSAttributedString *)_mString 
{ 

    NSArray * exclude = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"doctype", @"html", 
                         @"head", @"body",@"xml",nil];

    NSDictionary * htmlAtt = [NSDictionary 
                              dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute,exclude,NSExcludedElementsDocumentAttribute,nil];

    NSError * error; 

    NSData * htmlData = [_mString dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [_mString 
                                                                length]) documentAttributes:htmlAtt error:&error];


    NSString * sdat = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData 
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(sdat);

    return sdat;
}
```

Where _mString is

```
NSMutableAttributedString *pAttributedString = [pInputText textStorage];

NSString *pHtml  = [self convertUnderlineTextToHTML:pAttributedString];
```

Regards
Rohan

Answer (score 1):

`NSTextView` inherits from `NSText`, which has a `-string` method. So `[pInputText string` should do what you want.

Alternately, `TextStorage` is a subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString`, so if you want an attributed string you can just use the return of `[pInputText textStorage]` directly.

Comment: Thanks Smorgan, i will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

since `NSTextStorage` is a subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString` which has a method through its superclass `NSAttributedString` :[initWithHTML:baseURL:documentAttributes](http://file:///Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleSnowLeopard.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index.html#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithHTML%3abaseURL%3adocumentAttributes%3a), you can use this to get what you want. documentAttributes can be `NULL`.